# Cannot install pglogical

Tags: postgresql, yum, pglogical

I cannot install pglogical. I'm fallowing this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/chap-manageddatabases.postgresql-rds-postgresql-full-load-pglogical.html#chap-manageddatabases.postgresql-rds-postgresql-full-load-pglogical-replication

And part about pglogical installation has two steps (I'm using postgres 10.4):

```
curl https://access.2ndquadrant.com/api/repository/dl/default/release/10/rpm | bash
yum install postgresql10-pglogical
```

I'm getting an error though:

```
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
https://dl.2ndquadrant.com/default/release/rpm/packages/amzn/2/x86_64/10/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.


 One of the configured repositories failed (2ndQuadrant packages (PG10) for 2 - x86_64),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=2ndquadrant-dl-default-release-pg10 ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable 2ndquadrant-dl-default-release-pg10
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=2ndquadrant-dl-default-release-pg10

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=2ndquadrant-dl-default-release-pg10.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from 2ndquadrant-dl-default-release-pg10: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://dl.2ndquadrant.com/default/release/rpm/packages/amzn/2/x86_64/10/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
```

How can I install it?

Comment: 1) How did you install your Postgres server? 2)  2ndQuadrant got bought by EDB so I'm guessing the repos changed.

Comment: The tutorial is probably out of date.

Comment: Postgres was installed before on the server. Hard to tel how it was installed

Comment: Assuming it was installed from packages use `yum` to list installed packages and see where the Postgres ones came from.